# Best implementation for working with two same tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lot of tables of two.

For example: `application_drafts`, and `applications`. They have references for two another tables: `questionary_drafts` and `questionaries` respectively.

Difference is only that draft-tables have two additional columns: `is_actual` and `version`.

Draft tables are used for work on my server, and then they'll be checked on other one.

When all data is good, remote server update tables without `_draft` prefix.

I need to work with draft-tables and show non-draft-tables data for user. User can change draft-tables, and view non-draft-tables data, but he can request copy of non-draft-tables data, and I need to make copy of this data to draft-tables.

I have a lot of code, and what is less painfull implementation, for interchangable work with this tables?

And how implement models?

Comment: Hi @Alex, Can we create table `states` as polymorphism. So, `applications` and `questionary` can belong to it?

Comment: Do you still need the draft after it became a full application? It seems more natural to consider `draft` a status of an application.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep drafts. I can only change draft-tables, and get non-draft-tables from remote server. When remote server check draft and it's OK it change status of draft on `is_actual` = false

Comment: Why do you think you need two different tables and not just a single table and integer column (enum) to denote the state? KISS

Comment: It's not mine design, I have this fast and I can't change it)))